# How to dissolve a strong resin in difficult situation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, polymers, solvents

The resin is made up from two components:

Component A: silicic acid, sodium salt (less than 10% sodium silicate)

Component B: Diphenylmethane-4,4'-Diisocyanate, isomers and homologs (MDI,Polymer-MDI)

It has been cured in place, however it became stuck to a piece of equipment made out of rubber.
It is stuck several meters down a line so access is very limited.

Is there anything that would be strong enough in small quantities to dissolve or even loosen this adhesive?

Any thoughts on a mixture of water 90%, ammonia 8% and detergent 2%? 
Would I need a large quantity of this mixture or how effective would it be?
Or a mixture of the same except using sodium carbonate instead of ammonia?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Amides may be, theoretically, hydrolyzed by concentrated sodium hydroxide. Silicic acid esters usually are readily destroyed by exscess of fluorides, like ammonium hidrofluoride... though it is not a health-friendly compound.

Comment: It might help to add a highly polar organic solvent like DMSO or HMPT to help wet and swell the polymer so it will react more efficiently with the base.

Comment: cyclohexanone dissolves things like cumar, sylvalite, and NI100 resins